# ibtool fails to compile storyboard in Xcode 7.1 Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistoryboard, xcode7.1beta

Having updated from Xcode 7.0 Beta 3 to 7.1 Beta (all intermediate releases including the 7.0 GM had a crash-on-launch bug for my project, which has only been fixed in 7.1 Beta) I can't build my project due to the following error:

```
CompileStoryboard MyApp/Resources/Storyboards/Main.storyboard  
    cd /Users/me/Developer/my-app  
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"  
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..  
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --errors --warnings --notices --module MyApp --output-partial-info-plist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bwakexzthboxucdaodqtbbbwgsaz/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Main-SBPartialInfo.plist --auto-activate-custom-fonts --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 8.0 --output-format human-readable-text --compilation-directory /Users/me/Developer/my-app/MyApp/Resources/Storyboards/Main.storyboard  


/ com.apple.ibtool.errors */  
: error: Not enough arguments provided; where is the input document to operate on?
```

Xcode is configured to use the Xcode 7.1 (7B60) command line tools:

```
$ xcode-select -p  
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

And `ibtool` appears to be the correct version:

```
$ ibtool --version  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-/  
<plist version="1.0">  
<dict>  
  <key>com.apple.ibtool.version</key>  
  <dict>  
  <key>bundle-version</key>  
  <string>9046</string>  
  <key>short-bundle-version</key>  
  <string>7.1</string>  
  </dict>  
</dict>  
</plist>
```

**EDIT:** Comparing the output from a successful build in Xcode 7.0 Beta 3 (formatted for clarity):

```
CompileStoryboard MyApp/Resources/Storyboards/Main.storyboard
    cd /Users/me/Developer/my-app
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode 7.0 Beta/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode 7.0 Beta/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH="/Applications/Xcode 7.0 Beta/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/.."
    /Applications/Xcode\ 7.0\ Beta/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
    --errors
    --warnings
    --notices
    --module MyApp
    --output-partial-info-plist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bwakexzthboxucdaodqtbbbwgsaz/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Main-SBPartialInfo.plist
    --auto-activate-custom-fonts
    --target-device iphone
    --minimum-deployment-target 8.0
    --output-format human-readable-text
    --compilation-directory /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bwakexzthboxucdaodqtbbbwgsaz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app
    /Users/me/Developer/my-app/MyApp/Resources/Storyboards/Main.storyboard

2015-09-17 15:44:06.451 Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[1216:88742] Error creating notification handler for simulator graphics quality override: 1000000
```

with the unsuccessful one from Xcode 7.1 Beta:

```
CompileStoryboard MyApp/Resources/Storyboards/Main.storyboard
    cd /Users/me/Developer/my-app
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    export XCODE_DEVELOPER_USR_PATH=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/..
    /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool
    --errors
    --warnings
    --notices
    --module MyApp
    --output-partial-info-plist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bwakexzthboxucdaodqtbbbwgsaz/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Main-SBPartialInfo.plist
    --auto-activate-custom-fonts
    --target-device iphone
    --minimum-deployment-target 8.0
    --output-format human-readable-text
    --compilation-directory
    /Users/me/Developer/my-app/MyApp/Resources/Storyboards/Main.storyboard

/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
: error: Not enough arguments provided; where is the input document to operate on?
```

reveals that I seem to be missing a value for the `--compilation-directory` argument and so the path to the storyboard is being used instead of as the target file for compilation.

Is it possible to inspect/modify this compilation step or is this likely a bug in Xcode?

Comment: have you tried to remove Xcode->DerivedData folder?

Comment: Yup, that doesn't help unfortunately.

Comment: $ sudo killall -9 ibtoold
Also verify if your .storyboard file is in "Bundle Resources" and all targets are selected.

Comment: Issue posted to [Apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/18369). An Apple staff member responded saying this is likely an Xcode bug. Bug filed with Apple.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So thanks to an Apple support staff member, the solution is to move the `Main.storyboard` file from the Compile Sources build phase to the Copy Bundle Resources phase.

Comment: My storyboards are in the Copy Bundle Resources and it still fails :(

Comment: @the_critic Product --> Clean and then rebuild did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks, same problem here. It help me a lot!

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

Adding another potential answer for "Error creating notification handler for simulator graphics quality override". I got this error when I added a run script in xcode build phases, and then dragged the script to the sop to make it run pre-build. No idea why this happened, but when I dragged the run script window back down to the bottom it fixed it.